# Facebook og:image not displaying

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm running a wordpress install using the Facebook for Wordpress plugin to handle posting to a Facebook page.

Posts are publishing to the page but do not display the image referenced in the og:image meta tag - the image reference points to a youtube video screenshot, on youtube's cdn (something like http://i.ytimg.com/vi/S018IwrFd_4/0.jpg)

Running my urls through Facebook's object debugger returns exactly what I would expect (all properties present and accounted for).

Considering adding the images to each post, in a hidden div, but that seems like a ridiculous fix. Better thought than pumping out posts with not thumb

Anyone had similar problems? Better, anyone have a solution?

EDIT: still having issues here - added the og:video tag as a test, it works but obviously allows the video to be played in the newfeed, which is not the desired behaviour - I want the link through to my site. Have removed the video tag, leaving only the og:image and the inline img, and I'm back to the previous problem

With the video tag, I get the post title and description alongside the embedded video, with the image tag only, I not only get no thumb, but the rendered link is just the page url with no title or description.

All posts are scheduled with future dates, and all appear fine in the object debugger.

I'm running W3TC to cache pages, but wouldn't have thought that's an issue as the images aren't on my server

Comment: Is your `og:image` image size meets OP requirements? `200px by 200px`

Comment: That's a minimum size isn't it? Pics are 480x320 and appear in the debugger

Comment: #1 Do you have a the option to select from thumbnails? 
#2 maybe you have SEO plugin controls it
#3 clear your cache

Comment: I'm auto-scheduling the posts, so there's no opportunity to select a thumb. Caching isn't the issue, have tried cached/uncached/dropped/primed. Have added both an inline, hidden image, and the og:video tag, the latter seems to be working

Comment: _“the image reference points to a youtube video screenshot, on youtube's cdn”_ – maybe youtube doesn’t like that, and somehow blocks Facebook from requesting the images at the moment of sharing? Rather unlikely, I admit, if the debug tool show the images correctly – but have you tried copying the images to your own server beforehand and then have og:image pointing to that copy? (If only to ensure that this is _not_ what’s causing the error.)

Comment: I think it's something related to the Facebook share action - if I manually share (copy and paste link) it works fine. Might try a different sharing plugin. Have turned off W3TC to see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've resolved this one - I had W3TC installe but none of the caching profiles active. I've since disable the entire plugin and installed WP Super Cache instead and all seems fine. So far.